# PayPal SDK for iOS: Restore purchased items

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, paypal

Have someone played with the PayPal SDK for iOS ([Link](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/ios-integration-guide/))? I have successfully implemented it on one app. My question is, for non-consumable items (example, remove ads on your app), is there a way to know if the user have previously purchased the item?. I want the user to be able to restore purchased content if he changes device, reinstall the app or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple requires that all digital goods (such as removing ads) purchases be made via StoreKit, so this is not something that you could use the PayPal iOS SDK for anyway. That said, the answer is no -- the SDK currently only helps facilitate payments, not track history client-side.

Comment: Definitively is a pain to track purchase history with PayPal SDK

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could verify if a buyer has completed a payment.  You could use the TransactionSearch API to search your PayPal account buy the buyers email address to see if they have made a payment to you, and you could then get the details.  Also, if you are using IPN to record your transactions on your system/server, you could also query your own database for any transactions from the buyer.

Comment: Record and query my own database. That's the thing I want to avoid. No way to do that with the API?

Comment: You can use the TransactionSearch API to search for a match within the PayPal account.  This would be using the API against the PayPal system, not against your server.